# Client side routing: fragment versus path

Tags: javascript, url, web, routes

Has a consensus emerged on whether the fragment (`example.com#/foo`) or the path (`example.com/foo`) should be used when identifying and routing between different parts of a single-page web application?

Comment: What is a fragment? Do you mean using hash or pushState?

Comment: `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`